# Wikipedia API call return empty object

Tags: json, jsonp, wikipedia

I'm making this API call on Wikipedia but it return empty objects. I guess it's something to do with the format (jsonp?).

This is the call:

```
 apiCall = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&callback=?prop=info|extracts&generator=search&callback=?&inprop=url&exsentences=3&gsrsearch=";

////////////Get info from API///////////

$.getJSON(apiCall + userSearch, function(data){

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Maybe your `});` is not closed off correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is that it doesn't provide info/extract data it's because you missed a `&` character after the callback parameter. Speaking of which, you have two callback parameters.

If the issue is that it returns an error instead of an object with a "query" key, that's probably because `userSearch` was an empty string or something.